# I want to open a new window or tab on click of button using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DebuggerIndexFormHolder holder)
    {
        var result = _debuggerIndexFormProcessor.Process(holder.DebuggerIndexForm, ModelState);
        if (result.IsSuccess)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Item", new { id = result.SessionId });
        }


    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Item(string id, string inputId)
    {
        var model = _debuggerSessionViewModelBuilder.Build(id, inputId);
        return View(model);  // it opens the required view in same window
    }
```

HTML Code

```
<button id="submit" type="submit" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">Debug it!</button>
```

> ActionResult "Index" is called and which in turns calls ActionResult "Item" , passing session ID to action result "Item",  which fills model on session id basis then it calls View , I need to open this view in different window using same session id. 
>   Can anyone please help me ?
>   Thanks

Comment: When validation fails then also it is opening new window which is not expected behavior, can anybody help?  I am using formtarget="_blank"

Comment: I want this submit button to be enabled all the time, I have used below 
    $(document).ready(function () {
   $('#submit').on('error.field.bv', function (e, data) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (data.bv.getSubmitButton()) {
     data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
    }
   })
    .on('success.field.bv', function (e, data) {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (data.bv.getSubmitButton()) {
      data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
     }
    });
  });

Comment: using above code it gets enabled and again gets disabled. There is no form tag in the cshtml page .Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not something you can control from the server side code.  You need to add a`formtarget="_blank"` attribute to your `button`.

```
<button id="submit" type="submit" formtarget="_blank" data-loading-text="Loading..." class="btn btn-primary">Debug it!</button>
```

Whether that opens a new tab or a new window is dependent on the user's browser settings.

Comment: Thanks it's working , initially I was trying on Edge, there is some issue in Edge for post request, but it's working on other browsers.

Comment: When validation fails then also it is opening new window which is not expected behavior, do you have any idea?